# Changing GDM Login Screen Behavior: No gdm.d directory

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, gdm

I am running Fedora 28 and am attempting to disable the user list in GDM (as the machine is domain joined, this is undesirable). In CentOS 7 this is as simple as putting a file named "00-login-screen" in "/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/" with the contents:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
disable-user-list=true
```

In this case, there is *no* "gdm.d" directory. Creating it, and then putting the file in the directory does not work. I've seen elsewhere that a file needs to be created in "/etc/dconf/profile" called "gdm", but I have created this file with the contents:

```
user-db:user
system-db:gdm
file-db:/usr/share/gdm/greeter-dconf-defaults
```

and it makes no difference.

Has the procedure changed that substantially in Gnome 3.28.2 compared to 3.22.2?

EDIT: This problem now occurs in CentOS 7 as well, likely due to a Gnome update.

Comment: Sincere apologies for going *totally* off-topic, but 'No GDM' [Gina X Performance] was a huge underground euro dance floor hit in the early 80's... & now I can't stop singing it ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes it's making it rather harder to Google this than it should be. :P

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `/usr/share/gdm/dconf` , where you'll find a file called `00-upstream-settings` ; 
Make a copy of it and give it a higher numbered prefix (e.g. from 00 to 90). The settings are pretty self-explanatory.

If I'm not mistaken, it could be that the name of the corresponding setting has changed in the meantime, but adding `disable-user-list` and setting it to `false` should work anyway. Don't forget to run `dconf update` from your terminal to make the changes take effect.

Greets

Comment: The directory `/usr/share/gdm/dconf` also does not exist. The only directories I have in the `/usr/share/gdm` directory is: `autostart`,`greeter`, and `env.d`. `00-upstream-settings` only exists in the directory `/etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/`.

Comment: @thunderbird32 I'm sorry, I've just realized that we have different Gnome versions (I have 3.28.1-1) so on my machine it worked ...
Some time ago I had some problems logging in with 'light-dm', after which I switched to 'gdm'. In the worst case, another login manager maybe could also be an option ;-) good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
su -
mkdir /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d && chmod 0755 /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d
cat > /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-login-screen <<EOF
[org/gnome/login-screen]
disable-user-list=true
EOF
touch /etc/dconf/db/gdm && chmod 0644 /etc/dconf/db/gdm
dconf update
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Although this may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it addresses the issue. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.  Thanks.

Comment: This does not fix the issue either, and in fact the only difference in this from what I did, is creating a blank `/etc/dconf/db/gdm`. It current versions this file already exists, so this isn't particularly helpful.